# Composer autoload psr-0 doesn't find class

Tags: php, composer-php

This is my project structure

```
api
 |
 PicoApi
    |
     managers
             |
              ApiManager.php
     composer.json     
 index.php
```

This is how my composer looks like:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "PicoApi\\": "",
            "PicoApi\\Managers\\" : "managers"
        }
    }
}
```

This is my index.php:

```
//require Pico Api autoload
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PicoApi\Managers\ApiManager;

try {
    //initialize the API
    ApiInitializer::initialize();

    //initialize a new Api with the request
    $api = new ApiManager($_REQUEST['request']);
    echo utf8_encode($api->processApi());

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode(Array(Error::jsonErrorField() => $e->getMessage()));
}
```

in my ApiManager.php I included: `namespace PicoApi\Managers;`

And yet i get an error that it doesn't find ApiManager.php.

When changing the composer to psr-4 it does work, but I want it to be psr-0.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Perhaps the file should be called `ApiManager.php`, not `ApiManagers.php` (according to what you have pasted as project structure)?

Comment: My bad, its ApiManager.. I edited the question.. it was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the notation [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), so you **need** to use PSR-4. PSR-0 does not allow for an intercessory path between any portions of the class name. If you want use it you need move `src/managers/ApiManager.php` in `src/PicoApi/Managers/ApiManager.php` then

```
"psr-0": {
    "PicoApi\\": "src"
}
```

Comment: Ok I changed my structure and updated the question, can you please take a look? its still doesn't work

Comment: now ApiManager.php is in `api/PicoApi/managers/` but it must be in `api/src/PicoApi/Managers/`

Comment: Why does the src is required ? and where does the composer needs to be? in the PicoApi or one level up ?

Comment: The dir `PicoApi/Managers/` is required if you want use psr-0. Choose where you want to put these folders and specify it in `"PicoApi\\": "root_dir"`